# CoreBluetooth - writeValue. Receiver can't receive any data from my iPhone

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

This is a project with CoreBluetooth. I use my iPhone 5c to run it. The peripheral is a singlechip. iPhone can receive data from the singlechip. But the singlechip can't receive data from iPhone with `[_peripheral writeValue:value forCharacteristic:_writeCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];`

The following is a part of my code.

```
#define kServiceUUID @"FFE0"
#define kCharacteristicUUID @"FFE1"
#import "BTManager.h"

@interface BTManager()<CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>{
CBCentralManager *manager;
}

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *peripherals;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CBCharacteristic *writeCharacteristic;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CBPeripheral *peripheral;
@end

@implementation BTManager

#pragma mark - Public Methods

- (void)writeToPeripheral:(NSString *)dataString {
    if(_writeCharacteristic == nil){
        NSLog(@"writeCharacteristic is nil");
        return;
    }
    NSData *value = [self dataWithHexstring:dataString];
    NSLog(@"hex data:%@",value);
    [_peripheral writeValue:value forCharacteristic:_writeCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
    NSLog(@"didWriteTo%@ characteristic:%@ data:%@",_peripheral.name,_writeCharacteristic.description,dataString);

}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"discoverCharacteristic:%@ Error:%@", service.UUID, [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"Service:%@",service.UUID);
    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kCharacteristicUUID]]) {
            NSLog(@"setNotifyValuefor:%@",characteristic);
            _writeCharacteristic = characteristic;
            [self.peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any immediate issue with your source code you provided. What specific peripheral device are you attempting to write to?

I guess the questions I would have are

1. are you sure writeWithResponse is supported on that characteristic?
2. Are you receiving a response of any kind in `peripheral: didWriteValueForCharacteristic: error:`?

If you aren't seeing a response in the above mentioned delegate callback I would question whether the peripheral is responding to a write command correctly.

Comment: Everything is all right when I change the Bluetooth chip without modify my code. Maybe the chip has a issue. Thanks for your reply :)